# Keep count of records of one table in another

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a table that has records in it, customer purchase info (table a).  I want to make a reference table (table b) that keep tracks of how many purchases each person has made by running a count against table a.  So say Customer 1 has made 15 purchases that are stored in Table A, Table B would have the customers name and then showing a count of their 15 purchases.  Was wondering the best way to go about this.  Thanks!

Comment: The best way is to create a query when you need that information, not to try and store information that you need to then keep in sync.

Comment: To add to Dale's point, create a VIEW with that query if you want an object that you can query like a table, but encapsulate the logic.

Comment: You want a view, not another table. An Indexed View might be the best way if you are worried about querying performance. Please show your table schema and attempt so far

Comment: Agreeing with all Comments so far, storing calculated results persistently is an anti-pattern that would cause serious trouble in your DB design by breaking Mr Codd's _Database Normalization Rules_: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Denormalizing this information into a separate table is a bad idea. You risk update anomalies, and need to write complex and inefficient trigger code to keep it up to date.

You could create a view for this. Your best bet here is an Indexed View, which the server will maintain for you, and allow efficient querying.

The main restrictions on an indexed view (as opposed to a normal view) are:

- Only inner joins are allowed, no applys or subqueries or derived tables or CTEs.
- Grouping is allowed, but `COUNT_BIG(*)` must be included, and the only other aggregation allowed is `SUM`
- Must be schema-bound (all two-part tables references, no changes to underlying columns)

```sql
CREATE OR ALTER VIEW dbo.TotalPurchase
WITH SCHEMABINDING
AS

SELECT
  p.CustomerId,
  NumPurchases = COUNT_BIG(*),
  PurchaseAmount = SUM(p.Amount)
FROM dbo.Purchase p
GROUP BY
  p.CustomerId;

go
```

```sql
CREATE UNIQUE CLUSTERED INDEX IX_TotalPurchase
  ON TotalPurchase (CustomerId)
  WITH (DROP_EXISTING = ON);
```

You can now query this view as if it was a normal table, and the server will ensure it is kept up to date in real-time.

I do recommend using the `NOEXPAND` hint when querying it, for various reasons.

```sql
SELECT *
FROM TotalPurchase tp WITH (NOEXPAND);
```